# What is "Nordic hamstring curl" in Chinese?

Tags: sport

I've searched `nordic hamstring curl` and its synonyms `glute ham raise` and `natural ham curl` on Baidu. None of top Chinese articles had Chinese words for it, they just used the English words:

- http://www.actrainer.com/bbs/detail_703
- http://bbs.dabin69.com/thread-295004-1-1.html

Comment: iciba:glutes  臀部:臀大肌简称（包括臀小、臀中和臀大肌）,ham：大腿后部
raise：提升; 增加; 高处; 举起 curl：弯曲：example：
Raise one foot, curl the toes and point the foot down-wards.抬起一只脚，弯曲脚趾，使脚尖朝下 suggestion; 臀大腿后部弯曲/抬起

Comment: @user6065, thanks for the suggestion. if there's no formal term for it, I will use your direct translation.

Comment: My initial reaction to the title was "What is 'Nordic hamstring curl' in _English_?" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**诺迪克腘绳肌屈伸动作**

Doesn't seem to be widely used but it is a translation used by 北京体育大学图书馆, but I am not sure if that means anything or not.

[国际体育科教资讯服务 【科技前沿】](http://www.answerlib.org/MzA3NTU2ODUxNg_1202225834_db4d32086d0e8bd42fe47df8e2aaeaba.html)

> 采用新式腘绳肌测试仪可减少运动损伤发生概率
>
> 昆士兰科技大学9月29日报道，最近昆士兰科技大学（QUT）的研究人员研制出了一种具有突破性的仪器。该仪器可以帮助顶尖职业运动员评估并减少腘绳肌损伤风险。该仪器为目前全世界唯一一种可以在诺迪克腘绳肌屈伸动作（Nordic hamstring curl）中进行肌肉力量测量的便携式装置。 [国际体育科教资讯服务]
>
> [image: yup]
>
> 研究团队首次证明腘绳肌损伤风险是可以通过测量运动员进行诺迪克屈伸动作时腘绳肌的力量来进行量化的。腘绳肌力量提升10牛顿可以将腘绳肌损伤降低约9个百分点。澳大利亚的一些重量级俱乐部已经开始使用原型设备，而该研究团队也已经开始在橄榄球联盟、NRL、板球以及A-联赛（足球）俱乐部中开展相关初期测试。

Original information is from here:

[[PDF] 国际体育科教资讯服务 - 北京体育大学图书馆](https://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=13&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwii1KqV2IvLAhUEOxQKHSsoDyIQFghgMAw&url=http%3A%2F%2Flib.bsu.edu.cn%2Fdocs%2F2014-11%2F20141127111232403211.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFpUMNDpzqZHoqyXa_X6HMGoxbbNA&sig2=8xaBDtiBe6XCMZBB4-l_fw&bvm=bv.114733917,d.d2s)

> 诺迪克腘绳肌屈伸动作（Nordic hamstring curl）

edit:

[Beijing Sport University From Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beijing_Sport_University)

> Beijing Sport University (BSU) (Chinese: 北京体育大学) (formerly Beijing University of Physical Education), founded on November 1, 1953,[3](https://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=13&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwii1KqV2IvLAhUEOxQKHSsoDyIQFghgMAw&url=http%3A%2F%2Flib.bsu.edu.cn%2Fdocs%2F2014-11%2F20141127111232403211.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFpUMNDpzqZHoqyXa_X6HMGoxbbNA&sig2=8xaBDtiBe6XCMZBB4-l_fw&bvm=bv.114733917,d.d2s) has contributed greatly to the sustainable development of Chinese sport and physical education and has enjoyed the fame as one of the **key sport universities** in China.

I would imagine that they have good enough credit to trust the material they put out.

Comment: you are amazing. thank you for finding this!